# What's the difference between these two statements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I am doing my Set Theory homework right now and I'm in a question that asks us to determine the truth values of some statements. There are two statements that look really similar, which made me suspect that there's some difference in their truth values that I don't understand. Here are the statements:

$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists x>0 (\varepsilon < x)$

$\forall y \exists x (y< x)$

Is there really a difference? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I didn't mean different as in one statement concerns only positive, I meant different truth values as in one statement is right while the other is wrong. Sorry for not clarifying!

Comment: Doesn't the second statement permit negative values?

Comment: What do you mean by "really".  I'd say those are very different.  The first says for every positive number there is a number larger than it.  The second says for every number (positive or not) there is a number larger than it.  Now you might say they *imply* the same thing.  If the second is true the first most be true but that a *derived* implication.  It's not a stated part of the statement.  And actually the first need not imply the second.  Consider the set $(-\infty, 0]$. In that the first if vacuously true, but the second is false.

Answer (score 1):

They're not a priori equivalent. I'll assume we're working with reals, which is typical for this notation.

The first statement says that for any *positive* (real) number $\varepsilon$, there is some *positive* (real) number x greater than it.

The second statement says that for any (real) number y, there is some (real) number x greater than it.

The second statement implies the first, but without something else the first doesn't imply the second because you can't say anything about the case $\varepsilon$ *nonpositive*. Of course, if you understand that for any $\varepsilon \ngtr 0$ that $\varepsilon \leq 0 < 1$ (which is probably trivial in your setting) then in fact the statements are equivalent.